# Why is type coercion not occuring here?

Tags: javascript, boolean, type-coercion

My understanding of type coercion is that when the operands are of different data types, one of them will be converted to an "equivalent" value of the other operand.

```
x = true;

y = "true"; // This should be converted to boolean or should be truthy by default

if (x == y){console.log("Type coercion works")}
```